# Feasible to use Parse as web app PaaS?

Tags: heroku, paas

Parse (recently purchased by Facebook) is marketed as a BaaS, but the tech stack seems similar to a PaaS such as Heroku, and they [tout](http://blog.parse.com/2012/05/30/parse-launches-javascript-sdk-parse-for-websites/) their Javascript SDK for web apps.

Unlike Heroku, Parse has a very big free tier and it also manages the integrated MongoDB (whereas Heroku offers paid managed MongoDB add-ons from MongoLabs and MongoHQ).

Don't those two cost savings make Parse an attractive candidate for use as a PaaS for a web app? Or am I missing some important technical distinction between the two? It seems that the distinction between BaaS and PaaS is more marketing related than technology related.